# What Astras were used by Indrajit?

Tags: weapon, indrajit

I've read many differing stories, but exactly what Astras did Indrajit know how to use?

Comment: He knew how to use all different types of astras. He has the knowledge of unlimited astras which are in his quivers of unlimited astras and unlimited weapons. These were given to Indrajit along with many other equipment.I got this from "Yuddha Kandh" in the Ramayana.

Answer (score 3):

To be really honest, it is very broad and long to name all the weapons which Indrajit knows how to use, but I will try to mention some of his most potent skills and powers as mentioned in Valmiki Ramayana. In Yuddhakanda [chapter 80](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga80/yuddha_80_frame.htm),

Indrajit obtains a capacity of going out of sight while fighting, and
he did so during his battle with Rama and Lakshmana.

> स तु वैहायसं प्राप्य सरथो रामलक्ष्मणौ |
>  अचक्षुर्विषये तिष्ठन्विव्याध
> निशितैः शरैः [6-80-3]
>
> Meaning: Indrajit with his chariot, reaching the sky and remaining **invisible**, struck Rama and Lakshmana with his sharp **arrows**.

Beside arrows as mentioned in above verse, Indrajit was capable of using missiles.

> रावणिस्तु दिशः सर्वा रथेनातिरथः पतन् |
>  विव्याध तौ दाशरथी लघ्वस्त्रो
> निशितैः शरैः  [6-80-33]
>
> Meaning:Indrajit for his part, who was a superior chariot-warrior
> and who was **swift in discharging missiles**, rushed on towards all sides
> and pierced Rama and Lakshmana with his sharp arrows.

Indrajit also know how to use sword. During his battle in war with Hanuman, he created an illusory image of Seetha, and killed her.

> तमेवमुक्त्वा रुदतीं सीतां मायामयीं ततः ||
>  शितधारेण खड्गेन
> निजघानेन्द्रजित्स्वयम् | [6-81-29]
>
> Meaning :Having spoken thus to Hanuma, Indrajit
> personally killed that illusory Seetha, who had been sobbing all the
> while, with his **sharp-edged sword**.

Answer (score 0):

He is a great astradhari. He knows the knowledge of many astras including that of the three ultimate weapons of the trimurti's Brahmanda Astra, Vaishnava Astra and the Pashupat Astra. Source : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indrajit.

Comment: Do you have any other source beside Wikipedia? Wikipedia sometimes makes baseless  claims.

Answer (score 0):

Indrajit is **one of the best warrior and considerd as Ati-Maharathi** in Ramayana. In Ramayana war He had defeated Laxmana twice and Lord Shri Rama Once. I will try to list some of the Astra's used by Indrajit in Ramayana war

[1. Lord Rama and Laxmana Defated By Indrajit-](https://www.mythaktvindia.in/2017/08/blog-post_13.html):-
Indrajit Used weapon named **[Nagpash](https://www.mythaktvindia.in/2017/08/blog-post_13.html)** and left Rama and Laxmana unconscious.

[2. Lakshmana and Indrajita last battle](https://www.mythaktvindia.in/2019/01/Indrajit-Laxmana-Ramayana-Battle.html):-
Here indrajita used many astra's against laxmana. at the beginning of battle, Indrajit used **Lord Yama's weapon**. in the same battle he used **

- **Rudrastra**
- **Maheshwarastra**
- **Agneyastra**

These are the weapons indrajit used in Ramayana war. But apart from these weapons Indrajit has

- **Pashupatastra**
- **Brahmastra**
- **Naryanastra**

in his Armour.

[image: Use Of Divine weapons in Ramayana war by Meghnad]

Answer (score -1):

> Indrajit played an active role in the great war between Rama and
>   Ravana. He is considered as the only **Atimaharathi** class warrior ever
>   born on earth as told in the Ramayana, Mahabharata, Puranas and the
>   Vedas. He is one and only warrior who possessed the **three ultimate
>   weapons of Trimurti, i.e. Brahmanda astra, Vaishnavastra, and
>   Pashupatastra.** He acquired all kinds of celestial weapons from his
>   Guru Shukra, Lord Brahma, Vishnu and Shiva. By defeating the Devas in
>   the heaven he took their weapons and become the possessor of all kinds
>   of divine weapons of deva, asura's and trimurti's.[1] Indrajit subdued
>   both Rama and Lakshman, and later incapacitated Lakshman in their
>   second encounter. Indrajit killed 670 million Vanara's in a single
>   day, nearly exterminating the entire half man-half monkey
>
> Not even Trimurtis Lord Brahma, Vishnu and Shiva possessed the
>   ultimate weapons of their contemporaries. Indrajit was trained under
>   the guidance of Shukra and obtained all kinds of divine weapons of
>   man, Devas, Asura's and Trimurti's. The weaponry is categorized mainly
>   into two types. One is Shastra, a handheld weapon like sword, lance or
>   mace. The other is astra, a projectile missile invoked by reciting
>   hymns.
>
> **Meghanada was also an expert in magical warfare, sorcery and tantra.**
>   He was married to Sulochana, the virtuous daughter of the King of the
>   Serpents, Shesha Naga
>
> he fought fiercely and arrested both the brothers using his most
>   nefarious weapon **Nagapash** (a trap made of a million snakes). Both the
>   brothers fell on the ground breathless. They were rescued by Garuda on
>   behest of Hanuman
>
> Seeing his uncle Vibhishana at Lakshmana's side multiplied Indrajit's
>   fury manyfold. He vowed to kill his uncle Vibhisana along with
>   Lakshmana once and for all, letting loose the **Yama-astra** which he had
>   been conserving for punishing Vibhishana's perceived treason.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indrajit

http://www.valmikiramayan.net/yuddha/sarga85/yuddha_85_frame.htm

> tena viireNa tapasaa varadaanaatsvayaMbhuvaH | astraM brahmashiraH
>   praaptaM kaamagaashcha turaMgamaaH || 6-85-12
>
> "By his penance,
>   Indrajit obtained a weapon called Brahmashira, by way of a gift from
>   Brahma and also horses, which are coursing at his will."

http://www.valmikiramayan.net/yuddha/sarga80/yuddha_80_frame.htm

> He proceeds to the battle-field and releases a flood of arrows towards
>   Rama and Lakshmana, while himself remaining invisible in the sky. With
>   a network of arrows, Indrajit creates a darkness in the sky and
>   showers a multitude of steel arrows towards Rama and Lakshmana. Sharp
>   golden shafts arrows are then released by Rama and Lakshmana. Struck
>   by the arrows discharged by Indrajit, monkeys in hundreds fall down
>   dead

http://www.valmikiramayan.net/yuddha/sarga81/yuddha_81_frame.htm

> While Hanuman and his army are watching, Indrajit pulls Seetha by her
>   hair and unsheathed his sword. Indrajit kills the illusory living
>   image of Seetha, with his sharp sword.
>    Lakshmana informs Vibhishana that on hearing the words of Hanuma
>   saying that Seetha was killed by Indrajit, Rama fell into a swoon.
>   Telling Rama the secret of conjuring trick practiced by Indrajit in
>   killing an illusory image of Seetha, Vibhishana assures him of Seetha
>   being still alive

Comment: Which site is this quoted content take? Add relevant links from those websites. Adding whole link to Yuddha Kanda or Ramayana would be confusing.

Comment: Indrajit possessed Brahmananda astra, Pashupatastra and Vaishnavasta but he was not the only one who possessed it. Parashurama, Vashishtra, Vishwamitra, Parashurama and Arjuna also possessed it. Yes. Indrajit is an AtiMaharathi of Ramayana but so is Rama and Hanuman